# Integration using flex 4(MATE MVC) and MSMQ

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, integration, msmq, mate

I`m doing an application in air(flex4), as this is my first app, I need some advices to do the integration part.

All integration between my system and the back-end have to be done using MSMQ, alright, I have heard some libs that I can import inside my flex project to put and read messages in the MSMQ queue, but this is not my doublet, I would like to know, how it`s a good approach to do this communication, what I mean is, should I have an actionscript class, called for example MSMQService, and there, I should have the functions to put and read in the queue? or should I create a new custom tag in Mate, and have separate eventMap just to deal with the integration?! I know that there are lots approach, but if someone already done that, I would like to know how you did, like some good patterns.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

First, I've never used MSMQ and my answer will be generally for Mate and server communication(due to my point of view and 3 months experience).

Second, I don't think that your communication classes need another `eventMap`.

Overview of the structure of my current project:

- view classes, responsible only for showing user interface, we tried to not include any application logic in them.
- controller classes, one big all-seeing `eventMap` and bunch of events. The `eventMap` include logic for 'what view.event triggers what model.function'. There must be NO calculations or other application logic in the 'eventMap'.
- `modelMap` responsible for binding the one direction link between model and view, describing what must change in the view classes (UI) when something is changed in the model. `modelMap` MUST NOT allow the view classes to directly manipulate model, it is against principles of MVC
- model classes - the classes responsible for application logic. Also the communication classes are there. Something like `ServerCommunicationManager, class sending GET/POST/tec requests and requesting for response

MATE logic:

1.) Some View class is manipulated and this view sent some event. Example: user with name and password presses the login button (RegisterScreen.mxml)

```
dispatchEvent(new UserRequest(UserRequest.AUTHENTICATION, name, password));
```

2.) The `eventMap` instance receives the event in `EventHandler` and invokes some method in the `ServerCommunicationManager` class. Example:

```
<EventHandlers type="{UserRequest.AUTHENTICATION}">
   <MethodInvoker generator="ServerCommunicationManager"
                  method="signUser"
                  arguments="{[event.name, event.password]}" />
</EventHandlers>
```

3.) The model class method is invoked. Example: my example is stubbed!

```
public function signUser(user:String, password:String):void
{
   var passwordEncoded:String = encodePassword(password);
   var jsonMessage:Object = new Object();
   jsonMessage.type = "checkUser";
   jsonMessage.name = name;
   jsonMessage.password = passwordEncoded;

   sendGetRequest(serverIP, json, receiveResponseHandler);
}

public function receiveResponseHandler(response:Object)
{
   var userDetails:UserDetails = decodeJsonToUser(response);

   if(userDetails is NoUser)
   {
      FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(new ServerResponseEvent(ServerResponseEvent.NO_USER));
   }
   else if(userDetails is NormalUser)
   {
      FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(new ServerResponseEvent(ServerResponseEvent.NORMAL_USER, userDetails));
   }
   else if(userDetails is Administrator){...} else ...
}
```

4.) Back in the `EventMap`

```
<EventHandlers type="{ServerResponseEvent.NORMAL_USER}">
   <PropertySetter generator="UserModel"
                   targetId="signedUser"
                   source="{event.userDetails}"/>
</EventHandlers>
<EventHandlers type="{ServerResponseEvent.NoUser}">
   <PropertySetter generator="UserModel"
                   targetId="signedUser"
                   source="null"/>
   <PropertySetter generator="ViewModel"
                   targetId="state"
                   source="loginDenied"/>
</EventHandlers>
```

And in the `modelMap`:

```
<Injectors target="{RegisterScreen}">
    <PropertyInjector targetKey="state" 
                      source="{ViewModel}" 
                      sourceKey="state" />
    <PropertyInjector targetKey="userName" 
                      source="{UserModel}" 
                      sourceKey="signedUser"/>
</Injectors>
```

Overview: In this approach you can successfully decopulate view classes from communication classes. It works stable so far in our project.

Edit: Since I'm relatively new to Mate, if someone see errors in my approach he MUST make a comment about it. It really important for me if some of this logic is partially or entirely wrong.